# Firebase, requestPermission; Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token in Web Cloud Messaging

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am just beginning to use the Firebase Web Cloud Messaging and stumbled upon an issue where I can not proceed.

The cloud messaging is integrated with a Tizen Web application(Samsung device application), where the goal is to use cloud messaging and to receive messages.

The console shows´ Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ´ to a line in the .html file.

Here is where the code stops/malfunctions: return.messaging.getToken();

How do I need to solve this problem?

I tried using this Firebase [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client) (this link it the first page of the documentation)

This part is included and written to .html

```
</body>
<!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first         -->
<
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.4.0/firebase-app.js">               </script>

<!-- <script src="/__/firebase/6.4.0/firebase.js"></script> -->

<script
    src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.4.0/firebase-messaging.js">         </script>

<!-- TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
     https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#config-web-app -->

<script>
  // Your web app's Firebase configuration
  var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "confidential information",
    authDomain: "confidential information",
    databaseURL: "confidential information",
    projectId: "confidential information",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: "confidential information",
    appId: "confidential information"
  };
  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

  const messaging = firebase.messaging();

  messaging.usePublicVapidKey('!token!');


  messaging.requestPermission()
  .then(function() {
        console.log('Have Permission');
    return.messaging.getToken();
  })
  .then(function(token) {
    console.log(token);
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
  console.log('Error Occured.')


  messaging.onMessage(function(payload) {
    console.log('onMessage: ', payload);
  });
</script>

</html>
```

A .js file that had to be included in the application package

File name: firebase-messaging-sw.js

```
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.4.0/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.4.0/firebase-       messaging.js');

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
var firebaseConfig = {
apiKey : "confidential information",
authDomain : "confidential information",
databaseURL : "confidential information",
projectId : "confidential information",
storageBucket : "",
messagingSenderId : "confidential information",
appId : "confidential information"
};
// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const
messagin = firebase.messaging();
messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function(payload) {
    const
    title = "Hello World";
    const
    options = {
        body : payload.data.status
    };
    // normal web browser api in displaying notifications
    return self.registration.showNotification();
});
```

Comment: ```return.messaging.getToken()``` will definitely throw a syntax error

Comment: Hi. You are right, but the line includes a semicolon. return.messaging.getToken();

Comment: I suggest you read over the basics of JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

See:

- https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js#cloud-messaging
- https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/API/notification/requestPermission

> Deprecated requestPermission(). Use the native browser API Notification.requestPermission() instead.

In any case, try to use `Notification.requestPermission()`.